I keep getting this error when trying to include a plugin in ktor manually: Unresolved reference: statuspages
I am following the tutorial in ktor documentation and when I try to add the Status Page plugin manually I get a series of error; Bellow there's the code, and the errors I am getting.
fun Application.configureRouting() {

    install(StatusPages) {
        exception<IllegalStateException> { call, cause ->
            call.respondText(text = "500: $cause", status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        }
    }

    routing {
        staticResources("/content", "mycontent")

        get("/") {
            call.respondText("Hello World!")
        }

        get("/error-test") {
            throw IllegalStateException("Too Busy")
        }
    }
}

When hoving upon the install statement I get this error:
Not enough information to infer type variable B
public fun <P : Pipeline<*, ApplicationCall>, B : Any, F : Any> P.install(
    plugin: Plugin<P, B, F>,
    configure: B.() -> Unit = {}
): F

When hoving over the StatusPages statement I get this erro:
Unresolved reference: StatusPages
I have checked the dependencies and they are exacly the same as the tutorial says
   implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-cors-jvm")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core-jvm")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json-jvm")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation-jvm")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-core:$exposed_version")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-jdbc:$exposed_version")
    implementation("com.h2database:h2:$h2_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-host-common-jvm")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-status-pages-jvm")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty-jvm")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-config-yaml")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests-jvm")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version")

Has anyone been there and knows how to solve that problem?
I have checked the dependencies, and they're appearently okay.
I have started a new ktor project from the create-ktor-projet panel in the website and included the plugin from there and it worked. But I am curious about why doesn't it work to add the plugin manually.

Just wanted to answer my own question becaused I could solve the problem just by closing and reopening InteliJ. So if you having this problem right now, try to do this.
